# Cannot run "Hello world" program in Google Apps Script. Getting error message about using new version of Google Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am going through the book *Google Sheets Programming with Google Apps Script* by Michael Maguire and I am trying to run the following Hello World-type function:

```
function sayHelloAlert() {
  // Declare a string literal variable.
  var greeting = 'Hello world!',
  ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  // Display a message dialog with the greeting
  //(visible from the containing spreadsheet).
  // Older versions of Sheets used Browser.msgBox()
  ui.alert(greeting);
}
```

When I select this function and try to run it, it returns an error: `The api method 'getUi' is only available in the new version of Google Sheets. (line 3, file "Code").` How can I not be using the new version of Google Sheets? I have only just started using Google Script in the past week. How do I verify which version I am using?

Comment: did you create the sheet or copied a template from the book?

Answer (score 2):

You have to create a new spreadsheet in Sheets and from the Sheets menu go to Tools --> Script Editor. You cannot access scripts.google.com directly.

Answer (score 0):

For spreadsheet use, I would use the `Browser` Class:

[Google Documentation - Browser Class](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/browser)

If the spreadsheet is only going to be used by you, it's not a problem using `.getUi()` as long as you are using the new sheets.  But if other users are running the code, and are using the old Sheets, they would get an error.

I don't see any method in the Spreadsheet Class for getting the version of the users Google Sheet using code.  I don't know if the advanced Drive Service has that information in the metadata of the file.  But, if Browser Class or HTML Service can be used in both old and new sheets, then I'd just use one of those two.